# Is it possible to have an empty MySQL numeric field?

Tags: mysql

I want to have an empty field on a MySQL Numeric field. If I define the field to allow a NULL value it defaults to 0.00. Sometimes for this row item I prefer no value. I could probably create a different table to track these few items, but at this point I prefer a one table solution.

Comment: The correct approach is to use `NULL`.  That is quite different from 0.00, so I don't know why a `NULL` would default to a legitimate value.

Comment: Mysql is unlikely to convert `null` values to a number unless it is instructed to do so. However, it is possible that you pass an empty string as value instead of null and that is converted to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you did this with `DEFAULT`. Don't do that:

```
create table t1
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    thing varchar(100) not null,
    anInt NUMERIC(5,2) NULL DEFAULT 0
);

insert t1(thing) values ('fish');
select * from t1;
+----+-------+-------+
| id | thing | anInt |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 | fish  |  0.00 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me on mysql 5.7.12:

```
mysql> create table X (a double null);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> desc X;
+-------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type   | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| a     | double | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table X add column b int;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> desc X;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| a     | double  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| b     | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into X (a) values (1.3);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into X (b) values (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from X;
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
|  1.3 | NULL |
| NULL |    1 |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Note that there's no such thing as MySQL 14.14.  That sounds like a client version, but clients are generally backwards compatible and sometimes forwards compatible.  The server version is found with the query `SELECT @@VERSION;`.